# How to decode data from an ABI function call?

Tags: tokens, etherscan, contract-debugging

I want to get the appropriate data out when let's say I click `Swap` or `Approve` on a Dapp. I have been researching and have come across how to decode data from the `hex` that the dapp sends to my wallet. I understand there are libraries like `abi-decoder` and `@truffle/decoder` as well and the first 4 bytes represent the function name.

However, what I am finding difficult to decode is, let's say I want to convert 100 DAI to some UNI. I make the appropriate selection on UniSwap and then click `Swap`. The decoded function call comes out as `Multicall` and I want to get back the `token data` that I have just passed.

For ex - I would like to get the data back in some form that says I am paying 100 DAI in exchange for some UNI. How do I get this `100 DAI` bit out from the decoded params which I am getting from the raw transaction hex?

I hope I didn't make it super confusing, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi have you figured this out? Thanks

Comment: Hello, not entirely but I basically decode it on client side and have a list of common methods like Swap, Mint, Approve and the parameters they take. I look at the function signature and decode the params based on it. Its not covering 100% of cases,but does the job for common methods that people use.